# Referencing a td tag with an external js file

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, dhtml

I'm trying to reference a specific td id with an external Javascript file and am having trouble. I'm just trying to create a simple `mouseOver` event that will display some different content when the user rolls over an image in a table that is labelled like this:

```
<td id="lifeCalculatorButton">imagefoo</td>
```

in the external Javascript would I write the function like this?:

```
function mouseOver(lifeCalculatorButton){
  //some code
}
```

I'm a little lost overall as you can see...

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementById('lifeCalculatorButton').onmouseover = function() { ... };
```

... should help ;)

Alternatively, you could go the quirky route:

```
<td id="lifeCalculatorButton" onmouseover="MouseOver()">imagefoo</td>
```

Comment: Trying this, but it's not working. I know that the js file is linked to the html file correctly because i threw in some code into a window.onload function and it worked..any other ideas?

Comment: @user1086348 you might want to throw together a JSFiddle and/or post more of your code and/or an url so we can take a look on the overall situation.

Answer (score 1):

use getElementById

```
var el = document.getElementById("lifeCalculatorButton");
el.onmouseover = function(){
  //somecode
}
```

EDIT: changed it a bit :P

Comment: Uhm ... Does that bind the handler?

Comment: @vzwick it didn't... until I realized and changed it. (before I saw your answer btw) :P but good catch.

Comment: Trying this, but it's not working. I know that the js file is linked to the html file correctly because i threw in some code into a window.onload function and it worked..any other ideas?

Comment: @user1086348 Try placing all of your code relating to the tr element in a document.body.onload function just like you did the window.onload.  The DOM may not be fully loaded with your table before the handler is bound.

Comment: @user1086348 hm... have a demo handy? or could you recreate it on http://jsfiddle.net?